# PHP variable image dependent on status value

Tags: php, mysql

I currently hit a road block: i am trying to display a different "status image" dependant on the value of the "status" column in my sql. basically if repair status='01' it should show image 1, repair status='02' it should show image 2
etc.  here is the overview of the info which I have created:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Clients` (
`c_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`fName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`lName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`repair_status` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (c_id),
 UNIQUE (email);
```

(please disregard sql, i just created this from the top of my head. to give reference.)

I had originally set up the following:

*pull the data from sql ************************************************

```
   $q_user = "Select fName, lName, repair_status FROM Clients WHERE c_id='$_SESSION[c_id]'";
    $r_user    = mysqli_query($dbc, $q_user);
    $user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_user);
```

IF STATEMENTS ****************************************************************

```
if ($r_user[repair_status]="1")
{($_SAS= 'img/repair_Status/Repair_Status_01.jpg');}

else if ($r_user[repair_status]="2") 
{($_SAS= 'img/Repair_Status/Repair_Status_02.jpg');} 

else if ($r_user[repair_status]="3") 
{($_SAS= 'img/Repair_Status/Repair_Status_03.jpg');} 

else
{($_SAS= 'img/Repair_Status/Repair_Statust_00.jpg');}
```

it seems like this part is working properly, i am just unsure of how to call `$_SAS` to be the URL information in the `<.img src=" '$_SAS' width=100% "/.>`

any help will greatly be appreciated; also, i am unsure of where to specify `$_SAS` or if the way it is is correct. maybe there is a more simple way to get this code to work.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, I appreciate any help i can get.

Comment: you need to use == for the comparison, not =, and you need to check in the row, not the result so $r_user["repair_status"]="1" should be $user_data[repair_status]=="1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.  First of all for these lines, you should use the double = as stated in the comments above.  `==` means "is equal to", a single `=` sets the variable to equal to that amount.

```
if ($user_data['repair_status']=="1")
{($_SAS= 'img/repair_Status/Repair_Status_01.jpg');}
```

secondly, that's an odd looking variable; you are constructing it to look like a global.  why not just `$SAS`?

Regardless of that, you can just echo the values like so:

```
echo '<img src="'.$_SAS'.'width="100%">';
```

Comment: $r_user is the result set, $user_data is the actual row data.

Comment: i am still having an issue with the echo statement. The document is organized with php statements in the header followed by html body. would you recommend to make it all php? or is there another way to add the "echo" perhaps                                                                          <?php echo "<img src="'.$_SAS'.'width="100%">";    should this work within the html?

Comment: you need more consistency in your quotations.   if you are wrapping it in `"` you may need to escape the ones you are using in your html, or it will confuse the heck  out of the connection.  you can  do it this way if you want.  I just like this way `<?php echo '<img src="'.$_SAS'.'width="100%">'; ?>`

Comment: A better way would be, in the html section: `<img src="<?php echo $_SAS;?>" width="100%" />`

Comment: @nomistic i put it as you recommended <?php echo '<img src="'.$_SAS'.'width="100%">'; ?>   within the HTML and i got the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'            any recommendations?

Comment: There's a typo in his, it should be `<?php echo '<img src="'.$_SAS. '" width="100%">'; ?>`